# What font file type to use in Android WebView?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I'm successfully using font-awesome 4.7 in an Android Webview app, but the font folder contains .otf, .eot, .ttf, .woff and .woff2. I've noticed that these files are actually the biggest files in my whole package and increasing the size of the download by quite a lot, so I would like to choose the best one (or two, if necessary).

These ones have to work down to api 23, don't know if that makes a difference. Looks like Android Webview has used Chromium since api 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebviewClient, you can add the following method and trace the files that are loaded....

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

For my project that uses Font Awesome as part of another library, I see fontawesome-webfont.woff2 being loaded on both my phones (Pixel 2 [Android 9] and Samsung S5 [Android 6.0.1]).

This [webpage](https://www.theguild.nl/how-to-use-fonts-in-your-hybrid-mobile-app/) also has some interesting info on what platforms use which font file (and also says that .WOFF2 should be loaded on iOS 10+ and Android 4.4+)